# SharePointContextFilter attribute fails to rebuild SharePoint context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have developed a SharePoint add-in (SharePoint Online) and it is hosted in Azure. The add-in is an ASP.NET MVC application.

Here's the situation:

1. **/Home/Index**: The user starts on the landing page of the application and goes to the section `Actions`.
2. **Actions/Index**: On this page, the user has to select a few parameters and select an action to edit
3. **Actions/Edit/123**: The edit page opens, a form is shown with all controls filled in with the information about the action.
4. **POST**: After changing some fields, or none, the user clicks the *Save* button.

I didn't show it in the list but all the URLs have the `SPHostUrl`, `SPAppWebUrl`, `SPLanguage`, `SPClientTag` & `SPProductNumber` parameters.

This all works fine, except when the user doesn't interact with the application/page for a number of minutes and **then** presses the *Save* button. When the button is pressed, the application fails to pass the `SharePointContextFilter` attribute. The SharePointContext doesn't "exist" anymore. Following line returns *null*:

```
SharePointContext spContext = LoadSharePointContext(httpContext);
```

Normally, if it doesn't exist or isn't valid, the code will try and create it based based on the request. In the `CreateSharePointContext` method, the `contextTokenString` is always *null*:

```
string contextTokenString = TokenHelper.GetContextTokenFromRequest(httpRequest);
```

This is the code of the method:

```
public static string GetContextTokenFromRequest(HttpRequestBase request)
{
    string[] paramNames = { "AppContext", "AppContextToken", "AccessToken", "SPAppToken" };
    foreach (string paramName in paramNames)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Form[paramName]))
        {
            return request.Form[paramName];
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.QueryString[paramName]))
        {
            return request.QueryString[paramName];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

So, if this fails, the creation and saving of the context fails and the app returns the default error page.

This is the jQuery code that makes the call to the controller:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Edit", "Actions")' + window.buildSpAppParameters(),
    data: $("#updateForm").serialize(),
    cache: false,
    type: "POST"
});
```

Here's the code of the `buildSpAppParameters` function:

```
function buildSpAppParameters() {
    var spHostUrl = getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl");
    var appWebUrl = getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl");
    var spLanguage = getQueryStringParameter("SPLanguage");
    var spClientTag = getQueryStringParameter("SPClientTag");
    var spProductNr = getQueryStringParameter("SPProductNumber");

    return "?SPHostUrl=" + spHostUrl +
           "&SPAppWebUrl=" + appWebUrl +
           "&SPLanguage=" + spLanguage +
           "&SPClientTag=" + spClientTag +
           "&SPProductNumber=" + spProductNr;
}
```

Why does this initially work, but if the user waits a period of time, the code is unable to get/create the context again? Is there something I am missing and how can solve this?

Note: I am aware of following question: [Sharepoint 2013 MVC 5 provider-hosted app. Fails to authenticate on HttpPost using [SharePointContextFilter]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23828750/sharepoint-2013-mvc-5-provider-hosted-app-fails-to-authenticate-on-httppost-usi) and while there is useful information to read, it didn't help me further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This all works fine, except when the user doesn't interact with the application/page for a number of minutes

The session is expired and the SharePointContext is lost. So we need to regenerate the context.

According to the GetContextTokenFromRequest method, the context token should be passed in query string or forms. But from the buildSpAppParameters method, we can't found the context token is passed from the query string. The query string parameter should be named AppContext or AppContextToken or AccessToken or SPAppToken.

To solve this issue, you could check whether your current URL in your brower contains a query parameter named AppContext or AppContextToken or AccessToken or SPAppToken. If yes, you could read the value this parameter out from URL and pass it server in your buildSpAppParameters method. For example, if your URL contains a query parameter named AppContextToken, you could modify your code as following.

```
function buildSpAppParameters() {
    var spHostUrl = getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl");
    var appWebUrl = getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl");
    var spLanguage = getQueryStringParameter("SPLanguage");
    var spClientTag = getQueryStringParameter("SPClientTag");
    var spProductNr = getQueryStringParameter("SPProductNumber");

    var appContextToken = getQueryStringParameter("AppContextToken");

    return "?SPHostUrl=" + spHostUrl +
        "&SPAppWebUrl=" + appWebUrl +
        "&SPLanguage=" + spLanguage +
        "&SPClientTag=" + spClientTag +
        "&SPProductNumber=" + spProductNr +
        "&AppContextToken=" + appContextToken;
}
```

If your URL doesn't contain such query parameters, you need to modify your code to store the context token in cookie when the context token was got at the first time.

```
string contextTokenString = TokenHelper.GetContextTokenFromRequest(httpRequest);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(contextTokenString))
{
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("AppContextToken", contextTokenString);
    cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}
```

After that, the context token can be got from the cookie if the token haven't been passed through query string.

```
public static string GetContextTokenFromRequest(HttpRequestBase request)
{
    string[] paramNames = { "AppContext", "AppContextToken", "AccessToken", "SPAppToken" };
    foreach (string paramName in paramNames)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Form[paramName]))
        {
            return request.Form[paramName];
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.QueryString[paramName]))
        {
            return request.QueryString[paramName];
        }
    }
    if (request.Cookies["AppContextToken"] != null)
    {
        return request.Cookies["AppContextToken"].Value;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I implemented your cookie-suggestion, with some modifications to my situations though. The only thing I was still wondering about: is it safe enough?

Comment: You could  encrypt the token and send the encrypted token in cookie. After get the encrypted token back, you could decrypt it on server side. You can also extend session expiration time to solve this issue. You could store your session to Azure SQL or Azure Redis Cache and configure the expiration time of Session to meet your need.

Comment: I solved the problem eventually by extending the TimeOut property of the session. I'll definitly keep your answer in mind as it was helpful in understanding the problem, thanks again.